# Social feeds to display on EE driven website

Tags: add-on, facebook, twitter, social

I'm going to move one Wordpress site to EE and they have using social feeds (twitter and facebook, I think multiple sources) displaying on their website.

Are there any addons for EE which can handle that or any suggestions? I have take a look at [Data Grab](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab) and [Feed Parser](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/feed-parser), but both will require to create own tags or templates to display those feeds.

Comment: Any add-on you use is going to require you to write your own template code. That's how EE works. If you want something that's just going to dump the social content in there, you'll probably want to use each social platform's native tools for embedding.

Answer (score 2):

[EE_Twitter](https://github.com/click-rain/EE_Twitter) is a good free solution for embedding Tweets via the API (it does not create entries in EE's database).